# How to allow custom/catch-all domains in nginx?

Tags: django, http, nginx, nginx-config

I want each user to be able to point their own domain names at my Django server.

My current nginx config file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ looks like this:

```
upstream app_server {
            server unix:/home/zylvie/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
            if ($host = www.zylvie.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            } # managed by Certbot

            server_name www.zylvie.com;
            return 301 $scheme://zylvie.com$request_uri;


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/zylvie.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/zylvie.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
            server_name zylvie.com;

            keepalive_timeout 60;
            client_max_body_size 4G;

            access_log /home/zylvie/logs/nginx-access.log;
            error_log /home/zylvie/logs/nginx-error.log;

            location /robots.txt {
                    alias /home/zylvie/staticfiles/robots.txt;
            }

            location /favicon.ico {
                    alias /home/zylvie/staticfiles/favicon.ico;
            }

            location /static/ {
                    alias /home/zylvie/staticfiles/;
            }

            location /media/ {
                    allow all;
                    auth_basic off;
                    alias /home/zylvie/zylvie/media/;
            }

            # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
            location / {
                    try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
            }

            location @proxy_to_app {
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_redirect off;

                    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
                    proxy_send_timeout 600;
                    proxy_read_timeout 600;
                    send_timeout 600;
                    fastcgi_read_timeout 60;

                    proxy_pass http://app_server;
            }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/zylvie.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/zylvie.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
        if ($host = zylvie.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        if ($host = www.zylvie.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        listen 80;
        server_name zylvie.com www.zylvie.com;
}


server {
    if ($host = zylvie.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


            server_name zylvie.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.zylvie.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



            server_name www.zylvie.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I tried modifying the 2nd server block's server_name and did this:

```
...
    server_name  ~. "";
...
```

I then went into the DNS records of another domain I own (zlappo.com), and pointed zylvie.zlappo.com to the IP address of my Django server.

It should load my Django app, but all I get is the "Welcome to nginx!" page.

How do I fix it?

I suspect it might have something to do with the SSL/Let's Encrpyt certificate I have (which is domain-specific), but I'm not sure.

Comment: The regex name `~.` may match only one character, and it's missing the `^` and `$` to denote start and end, don't you mean `~^.*$`?  Please [refer to this section of the nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names). You may wish to use [wildcard names](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#wildcard_names) instead.